# Shortcuts App: Shortcut works with ChatGPT 3, but not ChatGPT 4

Tags: shortcuts-app, json

I have the following shortcut based on this [Youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gePhjvKdUro) that I adapted so it can save a conversation in Notes in a folder called `ChatGPT` (if you want to be able to use the shortcut, you must [generate an API key](https://platform.openai.com/account/api-keys) (login required) and replace `INSERT API KEY HERE` in step 1 with the generated key:

1. Text `INSERT API KEY HERE`
2. If `Text` `contains` `ADD API KEY HERE`

   1. Show alert `Edit this shortcut and paste in your API Key`
   2. Stop this shortcut
3. Otherwise
4. End If
5. Ask for `Text` with `What can I do for you?`
6. Set variable `inputVar` to `Provided Input`
7. Get contents of `https://api.openai.com/v1/completions`

   1. Method: `POST`
   2. Headers

      - (Key) Content-Type (Value) `application/json`
      - (Key) Authorization (Value) `Bearer` `Text`
   3. Request Body: `JSON`

      - (Key) model (Type) Text (Value) `text-davinci-003`
      - (Key) prompt (Type) Text (Value) `Provided Input`
      - (Key) max_tokens (Type) Number (Value) `2000`
8. Get text from `Contents of URL`
9. Get `Value` for `choices` in `Text`
10. Get `Value` for `text` in `Dictionary Value`
11. Text `Dictionary Value`
12. Show `Text`
13. Set variable `outputVar` to `Text`
14. Choose form menu with `Would you like to save your query and the answer`

    - Yes
15. Yes

    - Create note with `inputVar` `outputVar` in `ChatGPT`
    - Open When Run: (checked)
16. End Menu

Here below is the shortcut in (2) pictures:

[image]
[image]

I credited my ChatGPT account with 10.- USD because I would like to use ChatGPT 4 (instead of ChatGPT 3) as a pay-as-you-go service.

I tried to adapt the `Get contents of` portion of the code, as follows, but without success (all the rest of the shortcut being equal to the one above):

7. Get contents of `https://api.openai.com/v1/chat/completions`

   1. Method: `POST`
   2. Headers

      - (Key) Content-Type (Value) `application/json`
      - (Key) Authorization (Value) `Bearer` `Text`
   3. Request Body: `JSON`

      - (Key) model (Type) Text (Value) `gpt-4`
      - (Key) message (Type) Array (Value) `1 item`

        - (Key) Item 1 (Type) Dictionary (Value) `2 items`

          - (Key) role (Type) Text (Value) `user`
          - (Key) content (Type) Text (Value) `Provided Input`

The modified portion of the shortcut in picture:

[image]

But when I try to use it, it does not seem to pass through.

My question:

- How must the `Get contents of` portion of the shortcut be modified in order to communicate with ChatGPT 4 and make the shortcut to work?

---

P.S.: Obviously I tried asking ChatGPT, but model 3 does not know about the existence of model 4 and therefore could not help me...